# Issue In fetching for upcoming events

Tags: php, time, strtotime, between

SO I have write the code for getting the list of upcoming events in next 7 days and it is working fine and giving me the list of upcoming events.but the probmlem is that it is also giving the event record of past days also. Here is my code :

```
$today = strtotime("Now"); 
echo date('Y-m-d :H:i:s',$today)."<br>"; 
$leadDate = strtotime("+7 day", $today);
echo date('Y-m-d :H:i:s',$leadDate)."<br>"; 
$rs = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM names WHERE due_date BETWEEN CURDATE() AND '$leadDate'") or die(mysql_error());
echo "<b>Dues for upcoming 7 days</b><br>";
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($rs))
{
    echo $row['name']." => ".$row['normal_date']."<br>";
}
```

I have the table :

```
id| name | due_date | normal_date
|1|name1|1390245240|Mon, 20 Jan 2014 19:14:00 GMT
|2|name2|1390331640|Tue, 21 Jan 2014 19:14:00 GMT
|4|name3|1390418040|Wed, 22 Jan 2014 19:14:00 GMT
|5|name4|1390590840|Fri, 24 Jan 2014 19:14:00 GMT
|6|name5|1390850040|Mon, 27 Jan 2014 19:14:00 GMT
|7|name6|1390936440|Tue, 28 Jan 2014 19:14:00 GMT
|8|name7|1396034040|Fri, 28 Mar 2014 19:14:00 GMT
|9|name8|1398708840|Mon, 28 Apr 2014 18:14:00 GMT
|10|name9|1390158840|Sunday, 19 Jan, 2014
|11|name10|1390072440|Saturday, 18 Jan, 2014
|12|name11|1390176000|20 Jan, 2015
```

server's today's date is 19 Jan 2014 but it is also giving me the list of 18 Jan 2014 but i am looking for the next 7 days record.and my current script is giving me the following out put:

```
2014-01-19 :20:44:30
2014-01-26 :20:44:30
Dues for upcoming 7 days
name1 => Mon, 20 Jan 2014 19:14:00 GMT
name2 => Tue, 21 Jan 2014 19:14:00 GMT
name3 => Wed, 22 Jan 2014 19:14:00 GMT
name4 => Fri, 24 Jan 2014 19:14:00 GMT
name9 => Sunday, 19 Jan, 2014
name10 => Saturday, 18 Jan, 2014
name11 => 20 Jan, 2015
```

So Why the 18 jan 2014 & 20 jan 2014 coming in record, where i am wrong.Please Help.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
$rs = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM names WHERE due_date BETWEEN '$today' AND '$leadDate'") or die(mysql_error());
```

Instead of the `CURDATE` function use the `$today`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Broken...it solved my 1 problem of previous day coming in to the result but you can see in my out put the date for next year (20 Jan 2015) is also coming.

Comment: @user1168942 this is due to your unixtimestap is not correct there is `1390176000` which is not equals to that date check again the timestamp. The timestamp for it is `1390229100`. If this will help you then mark it as accepted.

Comment: Yes i think so..i am getting this `UNIXTIMESTAMP` from `$str="15 Jan, 2015";
echo $h=strtotime($str);die;` this code.is this wrong method ?

Comment: @user1168942 this is correct way. but you are taking the date as 15 Jan. first convert it to date format.